# Trouble in compiling the java code

Tags: java

I wrote the following piece of code in sublime text on my macbook pro.
I saved the file inside the java folder on my desktop. When I tried to compile the program and tried to execute it, I am getting the fallowing error message  " Error: Could not find or load main class Animals ".
Could someone help me in compiling and running this program

```
package forest;
class Animals{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Animals s = new Animals();
        Sring[] s2 = s.getAllAnimals();

    }

    public String[] getAllAnimals()
    {
        String[] s1= {"Lion", "Elephant", "Tiger","Deer","Wolf","Dinosar"};
        return s1;
    }
}
```

Comment: how did you compile and run it?

Comment: First you  should  fix your code, change Sring to String.

Comment: did you run compile and run a file named Star.java? I do not see any public class named Star in the code you have pasted.

Answer (score 2):

Make your class Animal as public and rename the file to Animal.java

Answer (score 1):

1. Your class is in a package called `forest` so you need to move `Animals.java` into a directory called `forest`.
2. You hava a typo on line 7: `Sring[] s2 =` should be `String[] s2 =`.
3. Compile from the parent directory of `forest`. Something like this should work

   ```
   $ javac forest/Animals.java
   ```
4. Run from the parent dir:

   ```
   $ java forest.Aminals
   ```

Your program will have no output when you run it.

Comment: @PRASANTHMAMAKAR You're welcome. Please mark this answer as correct by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look on your code there is no sring type class in java so change it to String

```
 Sring[] s2 = s.getAllAnimals();
    change it to 
     String[] s2 = s.getAllAnimals();
```

Everything will be good

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can name your java file with any name.
Say Sample.java. and let us consider this file is present in D:\work

Go to D:\work folder in cmd prompt.

*Keep this in mind :*

**If you write package forest, then your class has to be public.
So write public class Animals{}**

While compiling do this `javac -d Sample.java`
By doing this the compiler will create the folder "forest" and inside that it will create the Animals.class.
So now in D:\work we have Sample.java file and "forest" folder

Now in your command prompt DO NOT go inside the "forest" folder.
Stay in work folder. D:\work

And Run this command from D:\work  `java forest.Animals`

**Explantion::**

The name of your class that contains Main method is not Animals. It is **forest.Animals** This is the **fully qualified** name of the class. This happened becasue you put a **package** to it.
 So while runnning **you must run with fully qualified name**

```
 java forest.Animals
```

The name of your class is not Sample.java. <-- This is just  a **text file** name it anything the complier will not generate a class with name Sample.class because inside this file there is no such class, the class name is Animals. So Animals.class will be generated.

And `javac -d Sample.java` helps you create the folder structure automatically based on the package.

For example if your class was like this

```
package com.stackoverflow.samples
public class Animals{
}
```

And you do `java -d Sample.java`

**The Compiler will create a folder *com* inside that another folder *stackoverflow* inside that another folder *samples* and inside that a file Animals.class**

To run this you must run it from outside the the "com" folder with fully qualified name

```
java com.stackoverflow.samples.Animals
```

Answer (score 0):

try this tutorial [Java and the Mac OS X Terminal](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/mac-cmd.html) and Make your class `public` and also make sure that the file name that contains your source code and the name of your `main class` is same, your main class is the one that contains main method.